# Any good resource for java interview questions?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Can somebody point me to a good interview question repository for java/j2ee programming and architect position?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of the questions in @Sven's answer.

Comment: here is a good [interview question in Java](http://www.codelect.net/InterviewQuestions/Java-Senior-Level-Test)

Comment: here is a great place to practice blackboard Java questions http://code-exercises.com/programming/

Comment: You can find good QAs in this site, http://www.java-success.com/. But you need to get paid subscription for full access.

Comment: You can look at my tutorial on Apache Tomcat Interview Questions and Answers, https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/apache-tomcat-interview-questions-answers/

Answer (score 27):

How about SO?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64856/senior-j2ee-interview-questions
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72183/any-good-interview-questions-to-ask-prospective-junior-java-developers

Check the resources at this site, it has a very good collection of sample questions and answers: http://www.j2eebrain.com/j2ee-interview-questions-answers

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+interview-questions

Comment: @CarlManaster
0

questions tagged
java interview-questions

Comment: The first link has been deleted

Comment: Second link has also been as well.

Comment: j2eebrain dot com seems to have been taken over by a porn site.

Answer (score 4):

Check the book Java Puzzlers by Joshua Bloch. 
http://www.javapuzzlers.com/

[Amazon Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133678X)

Comment: Not sure about this one. An experienced Java programmer should get some of them, but then they should also have read the book.

Comment: This is essentially a book that documents weird corner cases in the Java language and could almost be considered a collection of trick questions. A bit harsh to ask them in an interview IMO

Answer (score 4):

check out - [Real interview Java Questions](http://www.java-questions.com)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.glassdoor.com/ has lot of good java questions and puzzles.

Answer (score 2):

One more link to [Java Interview questions](http://www.skill-guru.com/test/25/java-interview-questions)

Comment: Another link with 200 interview questions - http://www.buggybread.com/2013/07/java-interview-questions-and-answers.html

Comment: You can find good explanatios here http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/12/java-interview-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

JCEA question may be useful:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/152957/Architect-Certification-SCEA/certification/java-application-client

http://www.leocrawford.org.uk/work/jcea/part1/

http://www.sweber.be/SCEA/